# Ограничение на уникальность свойства и NULL значения

Tags: lsfusion

Подскажите как добавить ограничение на уникальность свойства, чтобы можно было вводить только одно NULL значение? Вот пример кода из документации:

```
CLASS Book 'Книга';
id 'Номер' = DATA INTEGER (Book);
book 'Книга' (INTEGER i) = GROUP AGGR Book b BY id(b);
```

В данном случае ограничение не срабатывает на NULL значения id. Проверял на последних версиях 4.2 и 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор [GROUP AGGR](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Grouping_GROUP/) является частным случаем GROUP MAX :

> - EQUAL является частным случаем агрегирующей функции MAX (или MIN), добавляя ограничение на одинаковость значения операнда агрегирующей
>   функции внутри каждой группы.
> - AGGR и NAGGR являются частным случаем EQUAL, но с еще более строгим ограничением: для каждой группы существует не более одного набора
>   объектов, операнд агрегирующей функции является одним из объектов, а
>   группировки включают в себя все остальные объекты. Агрегирующая
>   функция NAGGR отличается от AGGR только тем, что в случае ее
>   использования не создается ограничение (предполагается, что это
>   ограничение следует из семантики самих свойств операндов и/или
>   группировок).

Этот оператор добавляет ограничение вида :

```
CONSTRAINT (GROUP SUM 1 IF [GROUP SUM 1 BY id(Book b)](INTEGER id)) > 1 
    MESSAGE 'Дубликат';
```

Так как в ключах свойств не может значения NULL, то и GROUP SUM 1 также будет не определен для книг с пустым id, и ограничение не сработает.

В целом, с точки зрения логики, лучше избегать таких ситуаций, когда NULL считается допустимым идентификатором, и добавить NONULL на id. Но если существует такая потребность, то можно просто вслед за GROUP AGGR добавить дополнительное ограничение :

```
CONSTRAINT [GROUP SUM 1 IF NOT id(Book b) AND b IS Book]() > 1 
    MESSAGE 'Запрещено вводить более двух пустых идентификаторов';
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Понятно, что так лучше не делать. Просто это понадобилось в случае составного ключа, когда одно из свойств может быть NULL. Вероятно, тогда нужно вводить дополнительное свойство через конкатенацию всех остальных.